# Estructuras dinámicas Java

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Hola que tal hace un día publiqué un duda sobre una estructura dinámica de lista la cual no podía realizar, les cuento mi problema, tengo que realizar esta actividad que es encuentra en este enlace http://ozarate.net/clases/4a/actividades/unidad3/a7.php
Siguiendo cada paso de la actividad realicé estas 4 clases

Clase Elemento:

```
   public class Elemento extends Producto {
    Elemento Siguiente;

    public Elemento(){
        Siguiente = null;
    }

    public Elemento(String id, String marca, double precio) {
        Siguiente = null;
        super.Id = id;
        super.Marca = marca;
        super.Precio = precio;
    }  
}
```

Clase Producto:

```
public class Producto {
    String Id;
    String Marca;
    double Precio;
public Producto(){
    Id ="";
    Marca="";
    Precio = 0.0;
}
}
```

Clase Lista:

```
public class Lista{
 Elemento Inicio = null;
 Elemento Actual = null;
 Elemento temp = null;


 public void insertar(String id, String marca, double precio) {
 if(Inicio == null){
 Inicio = new Elemento(id, marca, precio);
 Actual = Inicio;
 }
 else {
 while(Actual.Siguiente != null) {
 Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
 }
 temp = new Elemento(id, marca, precio);
 Actual.Siguiente = temp;
 Actual = Inicio;
 }
 }

public String mostrar_Id(){

  String salida = "";
  if(Actual == null) {
    salida= "Se ha llegado al límite de la lista";
  } else {

    salida = Actual.Id;
    Actual = Actual.Siguiente;

  }

  return salida;
} 
    }
```

Posteriormente a estas tres clases cree el JFrame tal cual como está en el link del trabajo añadiendo este pequeño codigo:

```
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Lista Tienda;
    public Menu() {
        initComponents();
        Tienda = new Lista();
    }
```

en mi botón Insertar funciona bien agrega los Productos, el id, la marca y el precio

El problema empieza aquí existen dos botones con la siguiente especificación:

Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de inicio |<  mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del primer elemento y si la estructura esta vacía mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario que la estructura está vacía.

Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de avanzar >  mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del siguiente elemento y si la estructura está vacía o está en el último elemento mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario.

El problema surge aquí
en el post pasado me ayudaron a esta parte

"Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de avanzar >  mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del siguiente elemento y si la estructura está vacía o está en el último elemento mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario."

Que es el método Mostrar_id de la clase Lista

```
public String mostrar_Id(){

  String salida = "";
  if(Actual == null) {
    salida= "Se ha llegado al límite de la lista";
  } else {

    salida = Actual.Id;
    Actual = Actual.Siguiente;

  }

  return salida;
}
```

Ese método lo mando a llamar en mi boton">" con el código

```
txtId.setText(Tienda.mostrar_Id());
```

txtId(Es el nombre de la variable de mi textField)

Al hacer esto añado 3 productos y al dar click en el botón, me recorre todo a la perfección (Hablando solo de los ID), ahora lo que me cuesta trabajo y no se que hacer, como logro esto mismo, pero que lo muestre en Marca y Precio y al dar click en el botón me muestre todos los datos juntos del mismo productos, tanto su Id, su Marca y Precio. Mis variables de cada text field son txtId, txtMarca, txtPrecio, al inicio pensé en copiar el método de mostrar_Id y cambiar de esta manera

```
public String mostrar_Marca(){

  String salida = "";
  if(Actual == null) {
    salida= "Se ha llegado al límite de la lista";
  } else {

    salida = Actual.Marca;
    Actual = Actual.Siguiente;

  }

  return salida;
}
```

Pero al momento de llamarlo en boton, todo entra en conflicto y me revuelven datos de id con marca, como lo podría hacer para dejar funcional todo mi sistema? muchas gracias de antemano

el boton de "Siguiente" queda de esta manera pensando ya en el método de id y marca:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    txtId.setText(Tienda.mostrar_Id());
    txtMarca.setText(Tienda.mostrar_Marca());
}
```

Comment: ¿ `mostrar_marca` esta dentro de la clase `Lista`? No veo a donde vas a asignar la marca y el precio. Si están dentro del botón tienes que llamar tres operaciones que son `Tienda.mostrar_id()`, `Tienda.mostrar_marca()`, `Tienda.mostrar_precio()`. Por cierto. Normalmente las clases se nombran la primera letra en mayúsculas y los objetos o instancias en minúsculas. Te recomiendo cambiar esas variables para que sea más fácil acostumbrarte a leer código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentario Rafael, así es, el método mostrar_marca esta dentro de la clase lista y hago referencia a el en el boton con  txtId.setText(Tienda.mostrar_Marca());

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la parte del botón?

Comment: Listo lo he añadido al final de la publicación

Comment: Ya te han respondido. No tiene caso que te ponga mi respuesta que es similar. Solo agrega un get y un set para hacerlo más limpio.

Answer (score 2):

Se te hace un batidero de información porque en cada función estás recorriendo el nodo, es decir el el id pasa el siguiente nodo, al ejecutar la siguiente función pasas el otro nodo, entonces te devuelve el id del primero y la marca del segundo.

La solución es en lugar de devolver cadenas devuelvas el objecto

```
public Elemento elementoActual(){

  Elemento elemento= Actual;
  if(Actual != null) {
     Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
  }

  return elemento;
}
```

Para esto se elimina el método mostrar_id y mostrar_marca

Ahora en vez de hacer

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
  txtId.setText(Tienda.mostrar_Id());
  txtMarca.setText(Tienda.mostrar_Marca());
}
```

Cámbialo por

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    Elemento elemento = Tienda.elementoActual();
    txtId.setText(elemento.Id);
    txtMarca.setText(elemento.Marca);
}
```

Comment: Al poner el codigo de elemento

public Elemento elementoActual(){

  Elemento Elemento= Actual;
  if(Actual != null) {
     Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
  }

  return elemento;
}

me dice que no se encuentra la variable "Actual"  :(

Comment: le has cambiado los nombres a las variables? recuerda que java es caseSensitive

Comment: No, no las he cambiado, es que la variable Actual está en la clase "Lista" no en "Elemento"

Comment: Eso es un método y va en la clase de Lista no en la clase Elemento, lo has puesto ahí?

Comment: Disculpa, ya estoy un poco estresado, ya lo he puesto como método y sí todo jala perfecto, ya sólo queda el precio con Double intente hacer cast pero no me deja, no se si lo estoy haciendo mal  
 Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.setText(elemento.Precio));

Comment: Es al revés txtPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(elemento.Precio));

Comment: Bueno, por ahí iba el asunto, muchas gracias, ahora ya nada más me falta el boton de regreso me lleve al primer elemento, es parecido en codigo con algún metodo que ya este creado?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66677/discussion-between-edgar-saenz-and-sr1871).